# Negate a Condition in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I have the following condition, accordingly to that condition I create some resources, while if that condition is not met then I create other resources.

```
Conditions:
  ISProduction:
    "Fn::Equals":
      - !Ref Environment
      - staging
  ISNotProduction:
      "Fn::Not":
        - !Ref ISProduction
```

However, when I try to evaluate the template with the snippet above I get the error:

> Template error: every Fn::Not object requires one boolean parameter

How can I negate a condition in a Cloud Formation Template?
Or how can I use the negation of ISProduction?

I also tried the Condition below in a resource creation, but I but the template do not pass the validation because "Every Condition member must be a string".

```
Condition:
      "Fn::Not":
        - !Ref ISProduction
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can reference other conditions by using the Condition key before your Condition Logical ID.

> [Associating a Condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#d0e163465)
>
> To conditionally create resources, resource properties, or outputs,
>   you must associate a condition with them. Add the Condition: key and
>   the logical ID of the condition as an attribute to associate a
>   condition, as shown in the following snippet. AWS CloudFormation
>   creates the NewVolume resource only when the CreateProdResources
>   condition evaluates to true.

Your example should look like this:

```
Conditions:
  ISProduction:
    "Fn::Equals":
      - !Ref Environment
      - staging
  ISNotProduction:
      "Fn::Not":
        - Condition: ISProduction
```

Optionally you can write it in the short form:

```
Conditions:
  ISProduction:
    !Equals [!Ref Environment, staging]
  ISNotProduction:
    !Not [Condition: ISProduction]
```